# What are the k-vectors in Ewald summation?

Tags: forces, charge

Ewald summation is a common technique for computation of forces on charged particles in "infinitely periodic" (crystalline) systems.

I'm trying to understand Ewald force calculation from [this website](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~cfa22/msim/node49.html). The below image summarizes the two contributions to the force on a given atom $i$, from k-space and real-space.

What is the highlighted sum "summing over"? Is it all of the inverse positions of particles? Specifically how many instances of $\textbf{k} \ne 0$ should there be?

[image]

Comment: Eq. 318: [$\dfrac{2\pi}{L}\vec{n}$](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~cfa22/msim/node48.html#eq:ewald_u)

Comment: @CountIblis why do you choose $\vec{n}$ instead of $\vec{l}$? Does this mean the k-vectors are just (0,0,1) , (0,1,0), ... (n,n,n) ?

Comment: Yes and also negative integer coefficients, you need to sum over $\mathbb{Z}^3$

Comment: Note: No upper limit, you sum over integer components to infinity, excluding the zero-vector.

Comment: @CountIblis thanks. In practice (i.e. in computer simulation), though, a limit is often assigned... I know it to be $n=7$ in the case of my group's work. It would be unfeasible to do an infinite sum on a computer. If you know otherwise please let me know!

by the way if you use this as answer I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k$-space contribution is intended to be the *reciprocal space*. The mighty power of Ewald summation is to split a slow converging summation into two rapidly converging series: this trick is made employing the Fourier transform and evaluating the summation on the phase space.

The definition of the vectors $k$ are the ones such that the following holds

$$e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}=1$$

that is nothing but

$$k_i\cdot r_j=2\pi\delta_{ij}$$

where $r_i$s (*respectively* $k_j$) are intended as the basis vectors of the Bravais lattice (*respectively* reciprocal lattice).

The summation should go in theory over all $\mathbb{R}^n$ but as you can see numerically, after a cutoff of few $k$s (tipically $10\times k$) you can truncate your summation.